# Cakephp exit admin mode

Tags: php, cakephp

Say for example you are logged in as admin on your site and want to go to `http://yourdomain/cake/admin/controller/action`.

Now in view you have a link

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Back to Normal'), array('controller' =>'pages', action' => 'index'); ?>
```

Now this should lead you back to a NON admin page however in my case when you click this link you go to:

```
http://yourdomain/cake/admin/pages/index
```

And since there is no `admin` index (since i don't want to go to `admin` index) i get a not found exception.

The only way to fix this right now is if i Manuel remove the `Admin` infront of the url.

My question is how do i exit admin mode?

Comment: give 'admin' => false in the link

Comment: @binoy please set this as an answer this worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you `<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Back to Normal'), array('controller' =>'pages', action' => 'index', 'admin' => false)); ?>`